# Error while retrieving time from firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi guys I'm trying to retrieve time and date stored in firebase but I'm returning the time value in milliseconds. Can someone please help me solve this. 
[image]

This is my code

```
class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

  getList() async {
    databaseReference
        .collection("bookings")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.isDelete? "Delete User": "User List"),backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,),
        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: databaseReference.collection('bookings').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(
                      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) {
                        print(doc.data);
                        return ListTile(
                          title:  RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(children: [
                              TextSpan(text: "Boat_id : ${doc.data["boat_id"]}\n"),
                              TextSpan(text: "Grand Total : ${doc.data["grand_total"]}\n"),
                              TextSpan(text: "Number of Passengers : ${doc.data["no_of_passengers"]}\n"),
                              TextSpan(text: "Promo code : ${doc.data["promo_code"]}\n"),
                              TextSpan(text: "Date and Time(From) : ${doc.data["selected_from_date"]}\n"),
                              TextSpan(text: "Date and Time(To) : ${doc.data["selected_to_date"]}\n"),
], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
```

[image]

Comment: kindly post formate of date which come from firestore

Comment: i have attached a screenshot to my question please check

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i want to retrive the date and time as it is not in milliseconds

Comment: now you are retrieving timestamp, please post your firestore database, what is the format that you want for the time?!

Comment: i want it in this format 7:00:00 PM

Comment: https://www.epochconverter.com/ for reference

Comment: i have attached my firebase database screenshot to the above post please check

Comment: can you please explain how can i use it in my code

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
TextSpan(text: "Date and Time(From) : ${doc.data["selected_from_date"]}\n"),
TextSpan(text: "Date and Time(To) : ${doc.data["selected_to_date"]}\n"),
```

into this:

```
TextSpan(text: "Date and Time(From) : ${doc.data["selected_from_date"].toDate()}\n"),
TextSpan(text: "Date and Time(To) : ${doc.data["selected_to_date"].toDate()}\n"),
```

The `toDate()` method should convert timeStamp into a normal date, you can find the method here:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/6cd8c677a21f1da0e78b20186be3ba0b0de08cef/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/timestamp.dart#L69